# Continue after TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm taking a really long list and pasting chunks of it into a `textform` but for some reason the website takes a bit too long to process the list and I get a `TimeoutException` and I thought I could catch it and then continue but I'm not sure how to continue in the from the last `quote`? Or does anyone have any other suggestion as to how to handle this error? Or maybe avoid it all together?

```
for lst in chunks:
    textform.send_keys([quote+'\n' for quote in lst])
    try:
        pushQuotes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
        pushQuotes.click()
        textform = driver.find_element_by_name('quoteNumbers')
        time.sleep(3)
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        driver.refresh()
        textform = driver.find_element_by_name('quoteNumbers')
        textform.clear()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to keep track of where you are in chunks:

```
for i, lst in enumerate(chunks):
    textform.send_keys([quote+'\n' for quote in lst])
    try:
        pushQuotes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
        pushQuotes.click()
        textform = driver.find_element_by_name('quoteNumbers')
        time.sleep(3)
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        # now you can use i to keep track of where you were before the exception
        # here I'm taking a slice of chunks, starting with i
        for j, lst in enumerate(chunks[i:]):
           driver.refresh()
           textform = driver.find_element_by_name('quoteNumbers')
           textform.clear()
```